# Downloaded blob files blocked

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10

In my Google Chrome extension, I am doing the following:

1. Creating a text blob:
   `var file_Blob = new Blob([file_Content], {type: 'text/plain'});`
2. Creating a URL for the text blob:
   `var file_URL = URL.createObjectURL(file_Blob)`
3. Using the method [`chrome.downloads.download`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-download) to download the blob via the URL to a file:
   `chrome.downloads.download({
       url: file_URL,
       filename: file_Name,
       saveAs: true
   });`

This has been working fine until the last few weeks / versions (as of 2019/01/07, versions 71 or 70) whereby the downloaded files have been flagged as coming from the Internet.

> Security: This file came from another computer and might be blocked to help protect this computer. Unblock

[image]

Therefore, a warning window is prompting upon trying to open the files.

> File Download - Security Warning
>
> Do you want to open this file?
>
> Name: exampleFile_Name
>    Type: Unknown File Type
>    From: exampleFile_Folder
>    Open Cancel
>
> While files from the Internet can be useful, this file type can potentially harm your computer. If you do not trust the source, do not open this software.

[image]

I can't find anything online for this change in behaviour and, as far as I can see, I'm generating and downloading the files as per best practice. Can anyone advise?